# Merge ssh config

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

Is there a way to merge the ssh config file into one session?

Such as

```
$ vim ~/.ssh/config

Host sshtest1
    HostName 192.168.1.11
    User ec2-user

Host ssttest2
    HostName 192.168.1.12
    User ec2-user
```

into

```
Host sshtest?
    HostName 192.168.1.1?
    User ec2-user
```

I did a try, but got this error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname 192.168.1.1?: nodename nor servname
> provided, or not known

Suppose I have 9 nodes. I don't want to repeat that sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge common line like this:

```
Host sshtest1
    HostName 192.168.1.11

Host ssttest2
    HostName 192.168.1.12

Host *
    User ec2-user
```